# Plotting with xlim and ylim. Firt execution: works for top graph, but not for bottom graph. Second onwards: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tuples, typeerror

I'm having a problem to plotting with `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` using Python3 in Canopy editor as soon as using Python 2.7.13 in Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit). The objective is to plot two graphs (top/bottom) with x,y axis range limited with `xlim(0,8)` and `ylim(-8,8)`.

The problem is that in the first execution that's all right for the top graph, but limits (`xlim` and `ylim`) don't work on bottom graph and its generated with wrog scale. Worse!: from the second onwards execution it don't works at all and python shows the `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`, pointing `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` as wrog.
So, I restart the computer and its the same: works for the top graph in the first execution and don't works at all from the second onwards with error message `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`.

The code is shown bellow, as soon as .png images for execution error in first and second executions. (Please, click on link if the image don't appear automatically!)

The code bellow is from text material [Introduction to Python for Science, Release 0.9.23](http://physics.nyu.edu/~physlab/Lab_Main/PythonMan.pdf), at pages 87 and 88. It would works! You can find it on http://physics.nyu.edu/~physlab/Lab_Main/PythonMan.pdf.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create data
theta = np.arange(.01,8, .04) # x axis
y = np.sqrt((8./theta)**2-1)  # 1st curve
ytan = np.tan(theta)          # 2nd curve
ytan = np.ma.masked_where(np.abs(ytan)>20.,ytan)
ycot = 1./np.tan(theta)       # 3rd curve
ycot = np.ma.masked_where(np.abs(ycot)>20.,ycot)

# plotting
plt.figure(1)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(theta,y)
plt.plot(theta,ytan)
plt.xlim(0,8)    # <--- what is the problem here?
plt.ylim(-8,8)   # <--- what is the problem here?
plt.axhline(color='gray', linewidth = 1., zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=np.pi/2, color='gray', linestyle='--', linewidth = 1., zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=3.*np.pi/2, color='gray', linestyle='--', linewidth = 1., zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=5.*np.pi/2, color='gray', linestyle='--', linewidth = 1., zorder=-1)
plt.xlabel('theta')
plt.ylabel('tan(theta)')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(theta,-y)
plt.plot(theta,ycot)
plt.xlim=(0,8)   # <--- what is the problem here?
plt.ylim=(-8,8)  # <--- what is the problem here?
plt.axhline(color='gray', linewidth = 1., zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=np.pi, color='gray', linestyle='--', linewidth = 1., zorder=-1)
plt.axvline(x=2*np.pi, color='gray', linestyle='--', linewidth = 1., zorder=-1)
plt.xlabel('theta')
plt.ylabel('cot(theta)')

plt.show()
```

[First execution: limits work for top graph, don't work for bottom graph >> Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM9bK.png)

[Second execution: don't works at all! >> Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYzzy.png)

[Second execution error in Canopy editor >> Python3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVGgB.jpg)

Comment: So what is the difference between `plt.xlim(0,8)` and `plt.xlim=(0,8)`? The first is correct. The second is bad, because you assign a tuple to the name of a function. Hence when you try to call that function, it is a tuple. But, as the error says, `'tuple' object is not callable`. Since this is a simple typo, I would vote to close this question.

Comment: You're right. Thanks!

Comment: I corrected this and graphs works ok, but the bottom graph overlap the label of top graph... What's the problem?

Comment: That is a completely different problem to which there also a lot of solution out there.

Comment: You're right. I'll ask in other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.xlim=(0,8)` is the problem. You are trying to assign the tuple `(0,8)` to the function `plt.xlim`. You need to remove the `=` sign from that line.

So, change:

```
plt.xlim=(0,8)
plt.ylim=(-8,8)
```

to

```
plt.xlim(0,8)
plt.ylim(-8,8)
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!! Sorry for the nonsense. I'm newbie. I'm feeling silly... But I thank you!

Comment: I corrected this and graphs works ok, but the bottom graph overlap the label of top graph... What's the problem?